# how to unselected all legends except the other one legend it shouldn't unselected in echarts

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

here's the code:

```
const _this = this;
    const legendList = new Array();
    legendList.push("邮件营销", "联盟广告", "视频广告", "直接访问", "搜索引擎")
    this.option = {
      title: {
        text: "堆叠区域图"
      },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: "axis",
        axisPointer: {
          type: "cross",
          label: {
            backgroundColor: "#6a7985"
          }
        },
        formatter: function(param: any) {
          let res = param[0].name + "<br/>";

          for (let x = 0; x < param.length; x++) {
            res += _this.uploadIcon + ' ' + param[x].seriesName + ': ' + Math.abs(param[x].data) + '<br/>'
          }
          return res;
        }
      },
      legend: {
        data: legendList,
        selected: {
          '搜索引擎': false
        }
      },
      toolbox: {
        feature: {
          saveAsImage: {}
        }
      },
      grid: {
        left: "3%",
        right: "4%",
        bottom: "3%",
        containLabel: true
      },
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: "category",
          boundaryGap: false,
          data: ["周一", "周二", "周三", "周四", "周五", "周六", "周日"]
        }
      ],
      yAxis: [
        {
          type: "value"
        }
      ],
      series: [
        {
          name: "邮件营销",
          type: "line",
          stack: "总量",
          areaStyle: {},
          data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
          name: "联盟广告",
          type: "line",
          stack: "总量",
          areaStyle: {},
          data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
        },
        {
          name: "视频广告",
          type: "line",
          stack: "总量",
          areaStyle: {},
          data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
        },
        {
          name: "直接访问",
          type: "line",
          stack: "总量",
          areaStyle: {},
          data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
        },
        {
          name: "搜索引擎",
          type: "line",
          stack: "总量",
          label: {
            normal: {
              show: true,
              position: "top"
            }
          },
          areaStyle: {},
          data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
        }
      ]
    };
```

how to unselected all legend except the `搜索引擎` dynamically. if there's a new legend it will automatically disabled. example there's a new legend which is `Server`, then it will automatic unselected when it added.

here's the stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-c3qqyg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass all the elements to the selected {} property if you want to make it dynamic because by default it will select all the legends.

```
 selected: {
  "搜索引擎": true,
  "邮件营销": false,
  "联盟广告": false, 
  "视频广告": false,
  "直接访问": false 
 }
```

Comment: what if there's a new legend. it should be automatic unselected without editing the code.